# How do I resolve VS2022 error Xamarin.iOS.Windows.WindowsiOSException Could not install the application due to provisioning profile not found error?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, maui

Attempting to deploy my iOS app to local iPhone device results in the following errors from the Xamarin logs:

- "Xamarin.iOS.Windows.WindowsiOSException: Could not install the application"
- 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)

The following describes the context when this error occurs:

- App build is successful
- Recently generated code-signing certificates are installed
- provisioning profiles generated on Apple Dev website which include (apple signin) entitlements, the targetted iphone device identifier are downloaded and selected

It is possible for this error to go away if I just remove the "apple signin entitlement" then the app deploys to the device succesfully.  When I add the entitlement back in then the error described above re-occurs.

Comment: 1. What entitlements. 2. Are you using wildcard for them? App specific capability = need explicit App ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Go to XCode. Window -> Devices and Simulators. Pick your Test iPhone and right click on it. Click on Show Provisioning Profiles. If there is nothing there, click on the plus-sign and add it.

Also look at Properties on your Project, go to IOS Bundle Signing and at Scheme. Try manual or Automatic (Configure automatic to make it work).
[image]